# Load binary tree to replace the one Leetcode gives you

Tags: java, collections, binary-tree

I have completed the following question on Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-preorder-traversal/description/, but would like to be able to code similar questions within my IDE, so I can immediately see syntax errors. The problem is that Leetcode gives you the binary tree, and you just write the class `Solution`, so I'm not sure how to create and load the binary tree into `Solution`.

```
package cs_gator_problem_classification;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.xmlschema.List;

public class PreorderTraversal_Problem1 {       

     //Definition for a binary tree node.
     static class TreeNode {
         int val;
         TreeNode left;
         TreeNode right;
         TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
     }

    static class Solution {
        public ArrayList<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
            Stack<TreeNode> s = new Stack<TreeNode>();
            ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            s.push(root);

            while(!s.empty()) {
                TreeNode current = s.peek(); 
                s.pop();

                if(current != null) {
                    s.push(current.right);
                    s.push(current.left);

                    result.add(current.val);
                }
            }

            //result.add(1);
            System.out.println("result: " + result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
        TreeNode originalRoot = new TreeNode(3); 
        Solution solution = new Solution();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
so I'm not sure how to create and load the binary tree into Solution
```

### 1. Create the binary tree

Here are two simple method that you can create a binary tree for the giving root object.And you can make any kind of data you like by setting new left\right node.

```
public static void makeTreeData(TreeNode root) {
    if (null == root) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("root should not be null.");
    }
    if (root.val > 10) {
        return;
    }
    TreeNode left = new TreeNode(root.val * 2);
    makeTreeData(left);
    TreeNode right = new TreeNode(root.val * 2 + 1);
    makeTreeData(right);

    root.left = left;
    root.right = right;
}

public static void makeTreeData2(TreeNode root) {
    root.right = new TreeNode(2);
    root.right.left = new TreeNode(3);
}
```

### 2. load the binary tree into Solution

Just call `solution.preorderTraversal(TreeNode)` method with the TreeNode you just created. And you can see the result in the console.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("test");
    TreeNode originalRoot = new TreeNode(3); 
    Solution solution = new Solution();
    System.Out.println(solution.preorderTraversal(originalRoot));
}
```

Comment: Looks like a great answer, thanks. I will try implementing it later on